# Build multiple docker images in Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to create 2 different Docker images from 2 different folders.

My repo has the following structure:

```
.gitlab-ci.yml
node_app/
   src/
   package.json
   Dockerfile
php_app/
   src/
   composer.json
   Dockerfile
```

I have the following code in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
image: docker:stable
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

.build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - |

      IMAGE_TAGGED=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CONTAINER_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
      IMAGE_LATEST=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CONTAINER_NAME:latest

      docker build \
        --pull \
        --tag $IMAGE_TAGGED \
        --tag $IMAGE_LATEST \
        --file $CONTAINER_NAME/Dockerfile \
        $CONTAINER_NAME

      docker push $IMAGE_TAGGED
      docker push $IMAGE_LATEST

build node app:
  extends: .build
  variables:
    CONTAINER_NAME: "node_app"

build php app:
  extends: .build
  variables:
    CONTAINER_NAME: "php_app"

.test:
  before_script:
    - echo 'testing app'
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CONTAINER_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  stage: test

test node app:
  extends: .test
  variables:
    CONTAINER_NAME: "node_app"
  script:
    - ls -la
#    - run test scripts

test php app:
  extends: .test
  variables:
    CONTAINER_NAME: "php_app"
  script:
    - ls -la
#    - run test scripts
```

The problem is that the docker build **context** is not the application folder, but the root of the entire repository, thus container the code of all apps.

The result of the test jobs `ls -la` command are:

```
total 40
drwxrwxrwx    7 root     root          4096 Aug  6 08:46 .
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root          4096 Aug  6 08:46 ..
drwxrwxrwx    6 root     root          4096 Aug  6 08:46 .git
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root             6 Aug  6 08:46 .gitignore
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 Aug  6 08:46 .gitlab
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          5705 Aug  6 08:46 .gitlab-ci.yml
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root          4096 Aug  6 08:46 .idea
drwxrwxrwx    7 root     root          4096 Aug  6 08:46 node_app
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root          4096 Aug  6 08:46 php_app
```

If I run the exact same docker commands locally, the images build just fine, with the correct build context. However, inside Gitlab Runner the build context doesn't seem to do anything.

I've checked the official [Docker build reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) if there is anything related to this, but I can't find anything.
The only mention of an exception when using build context is:

```
You cannot specify the build-context directory (myfolder in the examples above) when using BuildKit as builder (DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1). Support for this feature is tracked in buildkit#1684.
```

but I'm not using that variable, and Gitlab also doesn't set it.

Also, the official Docker reference gives this example :

```sh
$ cd /home/me/myapp/some/dir/really/deep
$ docker build -f /home/me/myapp/dockerfiles/debug /home/me/myapp
$ docker build -f ../../../../dockerfiles/debug /home/me/myapp
```

These two docker build commands do the exact same thing. They both use the contents of the debug file instead of looking for a Dockerfile and will use /home/me/myapp as the root of the build context. Note that debug is in the directory structure of the build context, regardless of how you refer to it on the command line.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I would suggest to remove that `--file $CONTAINER_NAME/Dockerfile` argument from your `docker build` command because you are already saying that the context for build is `$CONTAINER_NAME`. One solution is to set `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` before your `docker build` command, but I think better solution is just simply `cd` to the `$CONTAINER_NAME` folder before the build.

Comment: Hi czende thanks for your suggestions. I’ve already tried both solutions before and that didn’t work. As I mentioned, running the same commands locally works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution for this is not related to Docker build at all. Look at your test `node app job`. You are running `ls` command in the folder which is used for cloning your whole repo. So in the fact you are running `ls` inside your image, inside the folder with the content of your repo.

This is the default behaviour of the GitLab CI job. It will clone your repo to the newly created folder and that's why you are seeing this output. Try to disable it with `GIT_STRATEGY: none` variable for both of your tests jobs or try to run `ls /somewhereelse`.

If you want to run your tests command for the content of your node/php image, it would be better to remove `image:` from the job and run it on the default pipeline image as `docker run $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CONTAINER_NAME:latest run test scripts`

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. I forgot that Gitlab just clones your entire repo in each job. It doesn't matter which image it uses. Much appreciated :)